# Неожиданная Runtime error в системе автотестов

Tags: c

Решаю небольшую задачу:

> Составить программу для работы с целыми числами в **троичной системе** счисления.
> Для хранения таких чисел использовать стандартный тип long int, но
> ограничиться только цифрами 0,1,2. Учесть, что при таком представлении можно работать только с числами, ограниченными диапазоном типа long int. В качестве диапазона чисел в троичной
> системе счисления можно взять значения от –2 122 222 222 до 2 122 222 222. Составить функции для выполнения простейших арифметических операций и вычислить значение выражения [image: ab^2-a(b-a)+b] (числа *a*, *b* вводятся с консоли в троичной системе счисления).
> В случаях возникновения переполнения, вместо значения результата выводить
> символ «!» и код той операции, при которой произошло переполнение:
> 1 – при сложении,
> 2 – при вычитании,
> 3 – при умножении,
> 4 – при возведении в степень.

Собственно реализовал я ее, можно сказать, "в лоб". Все функции просто переводят число из троичной системы в десятичную, вычисляют, переводят обратно. Добавил коды возврата, сигнализирующие об ошибках. Собственно, вот:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define INT32_MAX 2147483647
#define NO_ERROR 0b0
#define OVERFLOW 0b1
#define ZERO_DIVISION 0b10

int toBase3(int k, int* res) {
    if (k < -52487 || k > 52487) return OVERFLOW;
    int p = 1;

    while (k) {
        *res += p * (k % 3);
        p *= 10;
        k /= 3;
    }

    return NO_ERROR;
}

int fromBase3(int k) {
    int res = 0;
    int p = 1;
    while (k) {
        res += p * (k % 10);
        p *= 3;
        k /= 10;
    }

    return res;
}

int sum3(int a, int b, int* exitCode) {
    int a10 = fromBase3(a);
    int b10 = fromBase3(b);

    int res10 = a10 + b10;
    int res3 = 0;
    *exitCode = toBase3(res10, &res3);
    return res3;
}


int sub3(int a, int b, int* exitCode) {
    int a10 = fromBase3(a);
    int b10 = fromBase3(b);

    int res10 = a10 - b10;
    int res3 = 0;
    *exitCode = toBase3(res10, &res3);
    return res3;
}


int mul3(int a, int b, int* exitCode) {
    if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
        *exitCode = NO_ERROR;
        return 0;
    }
    int a10 = fromBase3(a);
    int b10 = fromBase3(b);

    if (a10 > INT32_MAX / b10) {
        *exitCode = OVERFLOW;
        return 0;
    }
    int res10 = a10 * b10;
    int res3 = 0;
    *exitCode = toBase3(res10, &res3);
    return res3;
}


int div3(int a, int b, int* exitCode) {
    if (b == 0) {
        *exitCode = ZERO_DIVISION;
        return 0;
    }
    int a10 = fromBase3(a);
    int b10 = fromBase3(b);

    int res10 = a10 / b10;
    int res3 = 0;
    *exitCode = toBase3(res10, &res3);
    return res3;
}


int pow3(int a, unsigned short p, int* exitCode) {
    *exitCode = NO_ERROR;
    if (a == 0) return 0;
    if (p == 0) return 1;

    int a10 = fromBase3(a);
    int res10 = a10;
    unsigned short curPow = 1;
    while (curPow < p) {
        if (res10 > INT32_MAX / a10) {
            *exitCode = OVERFLOW;
            return 0;
        }

        res10 *= a10;
        ++curPow;
    }

    int res3 = 0;
    *exitCode = toBase3(res10, &res3);
    return res3;
}

int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    //ab^2 - a(b - a) + b
    int res = 0;
    int exitCode;

    res = pow3(b, 2, &exitCode);
    if (exitCode & OVERFLOW) {
        printf("!4\n");
        return OVERFLOW;
    }

    res = mul3(res, a, &exitCode);
    if (exitCode & OVERFLOW) {
        printf("!3\n");
        return OVERFLOW;
    }

    int temp = sub3(b, a, &exitCode);
    if (exitCode & OVERFLOW) {
        printf("!2\n");
        return OVERFLOW;
    }

    temp = mul3(temp, a, &exitCode);
    if (exitCode & OVERFLOW) {
        printf("!3\n");
        return OVERFLOW;
    }

    res = sub3(res, temp, &exitCode);
    if (exitCode & OVERFLOW) {
        printf("!2\n");
        return OVERFLOW;
    }

    res = sum3(res, b, &exitCode);
    if (exitCode & OVERFLOW) {
        printf("!1\n");
        return OVERFLOW;
    }

    printf("%d\n", res);
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

При загрузке его в тестовую систему, получаю половину правильно пройденных тестов и половину *Runtime error*. Честно говоря, не вижу, где она может происходить. Компилятор предупреждений не дает, отладчик тоже. Я так и не смог подобрать тесты, чтобы сломать программу. Буду рад, если поможете найти такие.

---

*PS:* есть небольшой шанс ошибок в тестовой системе, так как подобные случаи уже встречались: при загрузке программы от имени другого пользователя пропадала *Runtime error*.

Comment: Проверки на переполнение перед умножением `if (a10 > INT32_MAX / b10)` и `if (res10 > INT32_MAX / a10)` работают неверно при отрицательных аргументах. Тестовые входные данные: `0 -1`.  P.S. Нехорошо называть собственный макрос именем `INT32_MAX`, т.к. такой макрос уже есть в заголовочном файле `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, оказалось, что код выше содержал две проблемы:

- Первая, как указал @wololo, действительно заключалась в неверной проверке на переполнение типа данных при отрицательных входных значениях. Исправил добавлением модуля.
- Вторая же была связана с тестирующей системой: оказалось, что каждый раз, когда `main()` возвращает ненулевой код, тест считается проваленным независимо от вывода программы в консоль. Замена всех `return code`; на `return 0;` исправила проблему.

Спасибо за помощь)